Setting Up a Unique "From Address" Subdomain for Emails in a New BU in SFMC
I want to set up a unique "From Address" with a subdomain for emails sent from a new Business Unit in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. What are the steps to configure the subdomain and set it as the "From Address"?
Do I need additional authorization or verification of the subdomain within SFMC?
Do I need to involve SF support in this process or IT who has access to DNS?


Do I need additional authorization or verification of the subdomain within SFMC?

Check your contract if you purchased an SAP (Sender Authentication Package).
This can authenticate the desired (sub)domain.
If yes, good. Think of the subdomain you want to use. Check if you received a form for the SAP, if not, reach out to SF to get a personalized link for sender authentication (this is the unpersonalized version, which doesnt show much: https://senderauth.marketingcloud.com/). There you'll have a form that asks the right questions.
If no, you need to purchase an SAP.
You can get one SAP per BU;
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&type=5

Do I need to involve SF support in this process or IT who has access to DNS?

Yes, both.
IT need to delegate the desired subdomain before SF can do much (aside of the contractual questions of purchasing).
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_subdomain_delegation_guide.htm&type=5
Successful delegation looks like this:

Go to: http://www.kloth.net/services/dig.php
Check the box “Trace”
Enter Domain and “Look it up”.

Expected:
you should see something similar to the following entries:
subdomain.CUSTOMER.com. 3600 IN NS ns1.exacttarget.com.
subdomain.CUSTOMER.com. 3600 IN NS ns2.exacttarget.com.
subdomain.CUSTOMER.com. 3600 IN NS ns3.exacttarget.com.
subdomain.CUSTOMER.com. 3600 IN NS ns4.exacttarget.com.

After delegation SF support can set up the DNS configuration for said delegated domain.
When support is done you'll do the testing via e.g.an email itself:
Send out an email to your own inbox from the relevant sendout BU.
In your email client, Go to View, Raw Headers / Source Code (you need to look at the email header).
In the Email header, you look for something like this:
dkim=pass
spf=pass
which shows the intended effects of the SAP (i.e. "a trustworthy sender domain")

You might not need an SAP, if you are OK using the SAP subdomain which already is applied to a different BU on the account. This will be used for tracking and image links in emails. Nothing very noticeable. One could use a private domain instead, if this is only a question of branding the sender (and another Cloud Page domain) - this is normally a cheaper SKU to purchase.
